# How does React store and react to changing state exactly?

Tags: reactjs

I am scraping a website that uses React for the front-end. So far it seems that I have to use their search form in order to arrive at the results page.

The problem is that the site clears out the search form's selected options from a dropdown (its `state`) every time the page is refreshed and therefore it makes scraping significantly slower. I know that it's working as intended, but if there was a way I could directly manipulate the state then it could speed up my scraper as opposed to re-selecting all the choices from the little buttons.

I don't think it uses any type of *persistent storage* or *local storage* at all, for every selection, otherwise the form probably wouldn't be cleared on refresh.

I can see that the years options for the form are always present in a `data-`attribute (`data-years=["2017", "2016", ...]`) but only for the years. And when a year (or any option from the dropdowns) is selected, a hidden field is populated with a value such as `<input type="hidden" name="year" value="2017">`.

Is this all that React uses for temporary storage (aka. *state*)—hidden fields?

And for the second part of my question, what type of event is fired off when there is a state change? How could I trigger it manually? When I select a year, for example, I want the form to give me the options for the next dropdown—given the year.

Comment: "Is this all that React uses for temporary storage (aka. state)—hidden fields?" There is no one way to manage state in React. However, using hidden fields for that purpose, if indeed that's what's going on, is very unusual.

Comment: I agree, it did seem unusual for React to be using hidden fields. But when you say "There is no one way to manage state in React" do you mean that different versions of React manage state differently? Or that React manages state differently depending on whether it's a React prop or state set with setState? @Jordan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React does not use the DOM at all to maintain state. The example you provided is simply a poorly written React app. Normally everything will kept in memory (closured code so nothing in window/global) and React will update the DOM as she wants. :)

This means I don't think you'll be able to read/detect React instrinsic state changes from the outside. Interactive scraping should work like a user using the page, without any hint of what tech it's really using.

Depending on the technology you're using for scraping, you could indeed simulate or generate the real DOM events. When we need to write some end to end tests for a React app using the ubiquitous Selenium server, we normally have to manually `click` on buttons, options and so on and allow time for the React app to react accordingly and do its magic (like fetching more data and updating the page) and afterwards read document contents to verify everything was working. It's basically "scraping" with a desired output to verify, your test assertions.

If you're scraping static pages only (curl style: fetch the HTML and work your way with the original HTML response), I don't think you'll be able to handle a Javascript form. You need your scraper to be interactive.

Something like PhantomJS apart from the mentioned Selenium/WebDriver may help.

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the case—that state is kept in-memory with closured code. That's astounding. Indeed, I am definitely using an "interactive scraper"—couldn't do it otherwise with a React site. Thanks for your answer! I would upvote it if I had the points :).